# Struggling to Get Array Data From Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have not been able to access items in an array that I am retrieving with redux. When I do console logs in the action itself, I am able to access array elements individually. But once that data makes its way to the component for display following the dispatch of actions, I have been unable to parse the data structure without error.

ListingActions.js:
If I do a console log here, I can parse through the different indices of the variable data without issue

```
export const getListings = () => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    dispatch({ type: LISTING_REQUEST })

    const { data } = await axios.get('/gmk')
    // I can access the elements of the array here without a problem

    dispatch({ type: LISTING_SUCCESS, payload: data })
} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
        type: LISTING_FAIL,
        payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message,
    })
}
```

ListingReducers.js:

```
export const listingReducer = (state = { itemListings: [] }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case LISTING_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true, itemListings: [] }
    case LISTING_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, itemListings: action.payload }
    case LISTING_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    default:
        return state
}
```

Snippet from store.js:

```
const initialState = {
itemListings: [],
nope: { nopeItems: nopeItemsFromStorage },
keep: { keepItems: keepItemsFromStorage },
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
function HomeScreen() {
const dispatch = useDispatch()

const freshItemListings = useSelector((state) => state.itemListings)
const { loading, error, itemListings } = freshItemListings

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getListings())
}, [dispatch])

return <div>{loading ? <p>Loading</p> : error ? <p>{error}</p> : itemListings.length}</div>
```

You'll see that I am trying to just access the length of itemListings. When I do so, I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'). I have done other things like itemListings[0], and other methods just to see what my options are, but each has resulted in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the issue was with properly setting up the initial state in my store. I did change some of the variable names as suggested to make readability easier as well.

Changes to store.js:

```
const initialState = {
listingData: { itemListings: [], loading: true },
nope: { nopeItems: nopeItemsFromStorage },
keep: { keepItems: keepItemsFromStorage },
```

Setting both the loading and itemListing portions to the proper initial state was ultimately the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with how you are updating **itemListings** in **ListingReducers.js**

```
case LISTING_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, itemListings: action.payload }
```

You must update **itemListing** using the spread **(...)** operator to preserve the current **state** described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
case LISTING_SUCCESS:
        return { 
           ...state,
           loading: false,
           itemListings: action.payload
       }
```

In your code, the initial state is never actually getting updated in your reducer.

See [Redux Documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#writing-reducers)

> They are not allowed to modify the existing state. Instead, they must make immutable updates, by copying the existing state and making changes to the copied values.

> WARNING
> In Redux, our reducers are never allowed to mutate the original / current state values!

```
// ❌ Illegal - by default, this will mutate the state!
state.value = 123
```

> TIP
> Reducers can only make copies of the original values, and then they can mutate the copies.

```
// ✅ This is safe, because we made a copy
return {
  ...state,
  value: 123
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have two  **itemListings** in your app, which i think is causing some confusion.

In here :

```
    const initialState = {
itemListings: [],
nope: { nopeItems: nopeItemsFromStorage },
keep: { keepItems: keepItemsFromStorage },
```

the default **itemListings** state from the store is an array.

Then in here:

```
const freshItemListings = useSelector((state) => state.itemListings)
```

**freshItemListings** is the same array and you are receiving it in the component

then in this line:

```
const { loading, error, itemListings } = freshItemListings
```

you are extracting a itemListings **property from an array**, which results to an error.

You have to define **itemListings** in the initial state as an object:

```
     const initialState = {
itemListings: {itemListings:[]},
nope: { nopeItems: nopeItemsFromStorage },
keep: { keepItems: keepItemsFromStorage },
```

Another solution is as you are already defining a initial state for **itemListings** in its reducer, omit the itemListings property in initialState object,

```
         const initialState = {
nope: { nopeItems: nopeItemsFromStorage },
keep: { keepItems: keepItemsFromStorage },
```